# Create SQL Server MDF database file to ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.NET 5 and have a question regarding the local database `.mdf` file. In ASP.NET, it is very easy to create a `.mdf` SQL Server database file and put it in the `APP_Data` folder. However, when it comes to ASP.NET 5, I could not find such function and I even could not create such file. Does anyone know how to create a SQL Server `.mdf` file in ASP.NET 5 project? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Add Item:

[image: Data -> SQL Server Database]

This will add an MDF file to the project. Next you need to connect it:

In your settings file, instead of the web.config, you define your connection string in a json settings file, [like this](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/22/ef6-asp-net-core-mvc6/):

```
{
    "Data": {
        "SampleDb": {
            "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\SampleDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is 3 years old but how to do same in ASP.NET Core